# ruby date.month in words inside a squeel search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, squeel

I'm using squeel, and I have a search method in my Event.rb model, which receives a parameter(string) from a text_field input

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.where{date.month.strftime("%B").matches("%#{search}%")}
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is, if the user enters "fe" or "ap" search in the Event.date.month for a match ("february", "april", etc). At the moment is working only entering the month number 02, 04, etc.

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use the [Chronic gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) to parse the input date and use that to get all events on that date.

A side note: The `find(:all)` is deprecated, you could use `self.all` instead, or even better `self.scoped` so you can chain more scopes later

Comment: I've tried chronic gem as you said, but is not exactly what I want, I don't want all the events on a date, I want, if for example the user enters mo, I want all the events that are on monday, awesome gem anyway I didn't know about it, thanks

Comment: Ok, will try to think of another way if I find some time. Hope you find another solution otherwise =)